# FMDB Move to First Result in FMResultSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb

I'm using FMDB to manage my database for my application. At one point, I pass an FMResultSet to another function. I need that function to be able to reset the FMResultSet to its first entry. I understand that I could do the following:

```
FMResultSet *results=etc.
results[0] //this is the first
```

but I also need to be able to iterate through that, using `results next` until there is no more elements. How can I jump back to the first element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417340/how-to-take-copy-of-fmresultset-in-fmdb-sqlite) that "you can only iterate over the result set once".

I've tried to verify this in the FMDB [documentation for FMResultSet](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMResultSet.html#//api/name/next). I haven't found the exact statement, but I can say that in my experience with the library - I would agree.

Currently, I believe the only way to reset FMResultSet would be to re-execute the query on the database.

Comment: Hmm that or copy the result set immediately and pass that copy to the next function, I guess. Alright, thanks!

Comment: Indeed, that would be more efficient